# Getting data from Lightning component

Tags: apex

So I want to get data from a lightning component and store it in apex class. Below is a picture of the component. I got 'Name' and 'Sales Campaign Name' from the website: http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/. And the other two below are drop downs. 
[image]

The code for this is:

```
    <c:customLookup objectAPIName="Sales_Campaign__c" IconName="custom:Sales_Campaign__c" label="Sales Campaign Name" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}"/>

    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Leadform Type">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <option value="1">Preliminary</option>
        <option value="2">Lead pricing</option>
        <option value="3">Preview Approval</option>
        <option value="4">Non-lead Approval</option>
    </lightning:select>

     <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Attachment">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <option value="1">Leadform: NE and RPFH</option>
        <option value="2">Leadform: MSA</option>
        <option value="3">Leadform: T and M  </option>
        <option value="4">Leadform: Restructuring</option>
         <option value="5">Contract: Review</option>
    </lightning:select>
```

So I want to store what ever the user has selected in an apex class. For example I want to store the selected 'Sales Campaign Name'  in a String. However, I don't know how to make that link. How do I access data from a lightning component? Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you considered doing [Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_prereqs)?

Comment: I have had a look at it. For the lightning select I have found that you can select data by using .find("selectItem").get("v.value")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to get the values.

1 - Add an aura:attribute to your component and then set it as the 'value' attribute on the lightning:select.

```
<lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Attachment" value="{!v.AttachmentValue}"/>
```

2 - Add an aura:id attribute to your lightning select, then in the controller use component.find('auraIdValue') to get the component. Finish this off with a component.get('v.value') to get the selected item.

```
<lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Attachment" aura:id="attachmentSelect"/>
```

Then in your controller method:

```
doSomething : function(component, event, helper){
  var cmp = component.find('attachmentSelect');
  var val = cmp.get('v.value');
}
```

With either of these options, you would then assemble a request to the server in your helper to update the database.

Comment: Ok, but dont you need to call the 'doSomething' method from your component?

Comment: Yes. you would need some sort of a button or action  to call 'doSomething'. This could be as simple as a button or onclick or onchange action. With lightning:select, you can add an onChange by putting this in as an additional attribute 'onChange="{!c.doSomething}" '.